# Chai expect() fails in forEach() on 2nd object

Tags: regex, typescript, cypress, chai, assertion

I am implementing a testcase in cypress where I want to match a list of dateTime values with a RegEx pattern.
All of this gets done in a forEach loop. It works for the first Item and fails on the 2nd item, even though they are the same.
[image: Same Item fails test]

Here is the code for reproduction:

```
const array = [
    "2022-05-23 14:39:43.145",
    "2022-05-23 14:39:43.145",
    "2022-05-23 14:39:43.120",
    "2022-05-23 14:39:43.120",
    "2022-05-23 14:39:43.096",
    "2022-05-23 14:39:43.096",
    "2022-05-23 14:39:43.074",
    "2022-05-23 14:39:43.074",
];
const dateTime = new RegExp(/\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d/gm);

describe('tesst',() => {
    it('should work', function() {
        array.forEach((object) => {
            expect(object).to.match(dateTime);
        })
    });
})
```

**Edit**
It seems like the bug was the global flag (/g) of the RegEx pattern. However I do not get why this is an issue here. I'd be thankful for an explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the example simpler to help eliminate factors,

```js
it('tests with regex', function() {
  expect("2022-05-23 14:39:43.145").to.match(dateTime)  // passes
  expect("2022-05-23 14:39:43.120").to.match(dateTime)  // fails
})
```

If you look at the `chaijs` library, this is how `to.match()` is implemented

```js
function assertMatch(re, msg) {
  if (msg) flag(this, 'message', msg);
  var obj = flag(this, 'object');
  this.assert(
      re.exec(obj)
    , 'expected #{this} to match ' + re
    , 'expected #{this} not to match ' + re
  );
}
```

so the active ingredient is `re.exec(obj)`, equivalent to `dateTime.exec("2022-05-23 14:39:43.145")` and if you console.log that expression, the first call succeeds and the second returns null - which `chai` interprets as a failure.

```js
it('tests with regex', function() {
  console.log(dateTime.exec("2022-05-23 14:39:43.145"))  // ['2022-05-23 14:39:43.145', index: 0...
  console.log(dateTime.exec("2022-05-23 14:39:43.120"))  // null
})
```

The reason can be found at MDN RegExp.prototype.exec() [Finding successive matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#finding_successive_matches)

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec() method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.
>
> When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's **lastIndex property** (test() will also advance the lastIndex property).
>
> Note that the lastIndex property **will not be reset** when searching a different string, it will start its search at its existing lastIndex .

If we check the `lastIndex` property after each step and repeat a few times, every 2nd date fails.

But after a failure `lastIndex` is reset and the next test succeeds.

```js
it('tests with regex', function() {
  console.log(dateTime.exec("2022-05-23 14:39:43.145"))  // ['2022-05-23 14:39:43.145', index: 0...
  console.log(dateTime.lastIndex)                        // 23
  console.log(dateTime.exec("2022-05-23 14:39:43.120"))  // null
  console.log(dateTime.lastIndex)                        // 0
  console.log(dateTime.exec("2022-05-23 14:39:43.096"))  // ['2022-05-23 14:39:43.096', index: 0...
  console.log(dateTime.lastIndex)                        // 23
  console.log(dateTime.exec("2022-05-23 14:39:43.074"))  // null
  console.log(dateTime.lastIndex)                        // 0
})
```

So you can make your loop work by manually resetting the `lastIndex`

```js
it('should work', function() {
  array.forEach(object => {
    expect(object).to.match(dateTime);  // passes every date
    dateTime.lastIndex = 0;
  })
})
```

(or removing the `/g` flag)